# HTML redirect to about:newtab

Tags: html

I simply want to do whats posted below but nothing happens when opening the HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Page Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="1;url=about:newtab"></HEAD>
<BODY>
Optional page text here.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  about:newtab doesn't do anything in Chrome or IE that I tested.

Comment: about:newtab is a firefox feature from version 13, and i'm not sure it's working on the other browsers too

Comment: Yes its a firefox feature. I want to set my homepage to my .html file, have it remind me about some things, (list too long to type) then redirect to my about:newtabs list. Thank you for your replies! :)